# VBA textbox input depending on another textbox input

Tags: excel, vba, forms, user-input

I have a VBA UserForm with some textboxes and comboboxes for users to fill in with information. I want the users to be unable to fill some of them if they select an option from another one. For example let's take combobox1 , which has multiple choices for the user to select: option 1, option 2, option 3, option 4. If the user selects option 4, I want the user to be unable to fill some of the other textboxes. Can you please help me out with the code for this, and where should I put the code? Thank you

I tried to find the answer but it seems like I don't know how to say it short to be easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ComboBox named ComboBox1 and you want a TextBox named TextBox1 to be disabled when 'option 4' is selected in ComboBox1 then you could use

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With TextBox1
        If LCase(ComboBox1.Value) = "option 4" Then
            .Locked = True
            .BackColor = vbButtonFace
            .Text = ""
        Else
            .Locked = False
            .BackColor = vbWindowBackground
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This code must go in the code-behind of the UserForm (press F7 if you are viewing the visual 'designer' of the UserForm). You will need to change all references to ComboBox1 (including in the 'signature' of the Sub eg if you wanted to add a similar Sub for a ComboBox named ComboBox2 then the signature would be `Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()`) and/or TextBox1 depending on the names of your controls.

Additionally, you may want to remove the `.Text = ""` line depending on your preference ... this line deletes any text the user has already entered in the TextBox when 'option 4' is selected as locking the TextBox, by itself, does not provide any visual indication of the fact that it is locked.

The two lines with `.BackColor` are optional ... they change the background color of the TextBox to make it 'look' disabled (or enabled).